# Are Photon raise event and rpc interchangeable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I've read a few forum posts that some people prefer to use raise event over rpc,
but I can't find the reason why they prefer it. Is raise event interchangeable with rpc?
I mean I get it raise event is easier to use than RPC , because RPC requires the gameobject holding it to have photon view. But is there a situation where I should be using rpc instead of raise event? Any input is greatly appreciated !

Comment: like you say yourself the main difference is that RPC is targetting a certain photonview instance while raise event can be in any (even static) class. I used it to create my own multiuser layer on top of photon only using raise event and doing all ID and user management myself allowing to push way beyond the 1000 objects per player limit ;) I also used my own byte based serialization so the photon events were basically really just the transport layer

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the time reading my question.
So raiseevent just basically allows us to customize on what to send while RPC is used for a more straightforward reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPCs and Events are very similar, but have some key similarities/differences:

#### Both:

- Have options for buffering: (`RpcTarget.*Buffered` and `RaiseEventOptions.CachingOptions`)
- Have options for encryption: (`RpcSecure` and `SendOptions.Encrypt`)
- Have options for targeting specific users: (`RpcTarget` and `RaiseEventOptions.Receivers`)

#### Only RPC(s):

- Require the `[PunRPC]` method attribute
- Require (and run) on a particular object with a PhotonView

  - if the object no longer exists on the remote, the RPC never runs and is dropped
- Have parameters defined by the method declaration only

  - Does support method overloading, but not optional parameters
- Can have PhotonMessageInfo parameter

#### Only RaiseEvent(s):

- Are always sent "ViaServer"

  - Your local client will be sent a copy of the event through the server, rather than executing locally immediately (assuming you're a receiver)
  - Can be circumvented by calling your `OnEvent` method directly, and using `ReceiverGroup.Others`
- Uses a callback target defining the `OnEvent` method
- Can be called without the need for a target PhotonView
- Parameters arbitrary defined, they must be manually parsed/casted by the client
- Have a limit of user-definable IDs: 1-200 (can be circumvented with parameters as sub-IDs)
- Can be sent both reliably and unreliably via `SendOptions`

*TL;DR: Generally, you'll want to use an RPC if something is related to a PhotonView, and a RaiseEvent call if not. They have basically the same capabilities otherwise*

Source: [Photon PUN Documentation: "RPCs and RaiseEvent"](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent)